Unable to Fetch Data from JSON File Using HttpClient in Angular 18
I am new to Angular 18 and have been trying to read a JSON file using an observable with an HTTP call. Despite following several online tutorials and forum solutions, I am still encountering issues.
My Setup
I created a service that makes an HTTP request to read a JSON file. I have verified that the path to the file is correct. However, I am not receiving any data, and I noticed that it says HttpClientModule is deprecated.
Code Snippets
EmployeeService (employee.service.ts)
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IEmployee } from './employeeInterface'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
  private _dataUrl: string = '/assets/data/employees.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._dataUrl);
  }
}

AppModule (app.module.ts)
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyTestPageComponent } from './my-test-page/my-test-page.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import { EmployeeDetailsComponent } from './employee-details/employee-details.component';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyTestPageComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent,
    EmployeeDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [EmployeeService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

EmployeeListComponent (employee-list.component.ts)
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IEmployee } from '../employeeInterface';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  template: `
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
    <ul *ngFor="let employee of employeesList">
      <li>{{ employee.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  public employeesList: IEmployee[] = [];

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(data => this.employeesList = data);
   
  }
}

EmployeeInterface.ts
export interface IEmployee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

Additional Information
The JSON file (employees.json) is located in src/assets/data and has the correct format.
There are no errors in the console, but the data is not being fetched.
I noticed a message indicating that HttpClientModule is deprecated, but I can't find any clear guidance on what to use instead.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Have you checked the request and what error code you get? 404?

@YongShun not getting any error. It does not fetch the data. The array is empty.

@Abdul please share stackblitz or github repo?

Please ensure that you configure the assets folder to allow accessing files & folders in the angular.json.
"assets": ["src/assets"]

Make sure your employees.json contains a JSON array.
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Emp One",
    "age": 44
  }
]

Besides, you are not using the employeeService in your EmployeeListComponent.
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployees()
    .subscribe((data) => (this.employeesList = data));
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

@YougShun that was a typo in the post.

Thanks for the help. One issue is resolved. It was with the assets folder  access.

But it is displaying in default component and still not displaying on other component. Checking that

Updated the StackBlitz with EmployeeListComponent, am able to show data.

Do you really use Angular 18? Where is your app config? You should use provideHttpClient() to use HttpClient. I think the deprecation message you got about HttpClientModule is because of that.
Look at this post HttpClientModule is deprecated in Angular 18, what's the replacement?
